# I get this error: Cannot POST /api/auth/signin When I do an API request in Insomnia

Tags: node.js, express

When I try to do my API request I get the error Cannot POST /api/auth/signin and the same in signup, but when I do my form fill in client side, it works fine.

auth.controller.js

```
import User from '../models/user.model.js'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import { errorHandler } from '../utils/error.js'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

export const signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body; // Extrae los datos del body en el HTML
  
  if (!password) {
    return next(errorHandler(400, "La contraseña es requerida"));
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  bcrypt.hash(password, salt, async (err, hash) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const newUser = new User({ username, email, password: hash }); // Crea un nuevo usuario con los datos del body
    try {
      await newUser.save(); // Guarda el nuevo usuario en la base de datos
      res.status(201).json("Usuario creado correctamente"); // Muestra un mensaje de éxito
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  });
};
export const signin = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body
  try {
    const validUser = await User.findOne({ email })
    if (!validUser) return next(errorHandler(404, 'El usuario no existe'))

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, validUser.password)
    if (!validPassword)
      return next(errorHandler(401, 'La contraseña no es correcta'))

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: validUser._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

    // Mantenemos la estructura de la respuesta, pero añadimos el token en el objeto de respuesta
    res
      .cookie('access_token', token, {
        httpOnly: true
      })
      .status(200)
      .json(validUser)
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
}
```

auth.route.js

```
import express from 'express';
import { signin, signup } from '../controllers/auth.controller.js';

const router = express.Router(); // Crea un nuevo router
router.post('/signup', signup); // Ruta para crear un nuevo usuario
router.post('/sign', signin); // Ruta para crear un nuevo usuario

export default router;
```

I change the library bcryptjs to bcrypt and I fix some error of Illegal Arguments but now I get this fail

Comment: _`router.post('/sign', signin)`_  the URL suffix seems to be `/sign`, **not** `/signin`